# Functions with varchar parameters of generic length

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

My goal is to create a MySQL function which takes any string and returns a modified version of it. The details are unimportant, and my problem is with the signature. I'm mostly seeking validation on what is the best practice for functions like this.

This is a (not working) vision of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
CREATE FUNCTION example1(param VARCHAR(n))
RETURNS VARCHAR(n)
BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(n);
    SET result = param;
    -- do stuff --
    RETURN result;
END//
```

Working with this, this weird interaction came up:

```
CREATE FUNCTION example1(param VARCHAR(35))
RETURNS VARCHAR(35)
BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(35);
    SET result = param;
    -- do stuff --
    RETURN result;
END//

CREATE FUNCTION example2(param VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(10);
    SET result = example1(param);
    -- do stuff --
    RETURN result;
END//
```

So example2 still works. This seems the varchar length is only validated on the input.
Then, to handle all strings, I get this for my production function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION example1(param VARCHAR(10000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(10000)
BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(10000);
    SET result = param;
    -- do stuff --
    RETURN result;
END//
```

Now the signature of the function is messed up. It works, I can set a column with smaller varchar using it -- but who would call such a function not knowing implementation details?
Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: What weird interaction and what do you mean by signature and implementation details?

Comment: Assinging the VARCHAR(35) result of example1 to VARCHAR(10) result field in example2.
By signature I mean you would never set a column of let's say length 50 with the result of the final function which returns VARCHAR(10000), unless you knew the implementation.

Comment: I think you need to have another look at the storage requirements for varchar fields and I would change them to text data types.